# Gradle new configuration in multi-project build

Tags: java, gradle

I created a new configuration in multi-project build and it doesn't download dependencies I assigned to it. Can't find any example on multi-project with new configuration on the net. Did anyone faced similar issue?

In my build.gradle root file:

```
allprojects {
    configurations {
      myConf
    }
}
```

Then in my build.gradle child:

```
dependencies {
    myConf 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.6'
}
```

Project does not compile, when I change myConf to compile configuration it compiles correctly.

Comment: Please show som ecode/config, our cristal globe is not yet delivered

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies of a configuration are only downloaded when the configuration is used. As the Java compiler uses the `compile` configuration, your `myconf` configuration is not used, so its dependencies are not downloaded.

Comment: My answer explains why Gradle does not download the dependencies. But apparently you have some need that (you assume) requires an additional configuration. Maybe you should post a new question explaining what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense for me. Just to explain what I want to achieve: I have my main app and additional component (aspect). I want to treat aspect's dependencies differently than my app's dependencies (copy to different lib directory)

Comment: The problem is that I need these dependencies to compilation as well. Can one dependency be assigned to more than one config?

Comment: I would advise to use separate modules for your app and your component. The best practice is to have one output artifact per module (to be more precise: to only have output artifacts that all share the same source. For example, see Android builds: one app module, multiple APKs). In your case you want to have an app and a component with different sources in the same module.